# Git best practice: getting the list of branches not tracked locally

Tags: git

I have a question about how to get the new branches availables on the remote repository.

I know there is (at least) two ways to proceed:

- `git pull` : pull the current working branch (fetch + merge) and get the list of new branches
- `git branch -r` followed by `git branch --track theBranch origin/theBranch` : track the new branch

Is there a recommended way to proceed (because of difference of behaviors)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there is necessarily a recommended way to proceed, because each of the two options do different things and have different use cases.

Doing a `git pull` will fetch all new remote tracking branches, as well as updating existing ones, and should list the new branches which came in at least.  But it won't actually create any new local branches.

Doing `git branch -r` will list all remote tracking branches, but won't actually update them with any new information on the remote.  The command

```
git branch --track theBranch origin/theBranch
```

will create a new local branch called `theBranch` which tracks a remote tracking branch bearing the same name.  This would be the same behavior if you were to do the following:

```
git checkout origin/theBranch
git checkout -b theBranch
```

Which option you choose to use depends on your goals.  If you just want to update the remote tracking branches and maybe list any new branches coming in, the doing a `git fetch` (or `git pull`) is satisfactory.  If you want to create a new branch, then your second option, or the option I gave, is the way to go.

Comment: `git checkout theBranch` is, in my opinion, the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tim Biegeleisen mentioned in his answer, it's totally upto to you which approach you would like to follow.

I follow `git pull --rebase` which actually rebase my local branch with remote and commit my local changes on top of it instead of [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) which is `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.